# Problem with converting the elements of the queue in C

Tags: c, binary, queue, decimal, dynamic-programming

The exercise is next:

### "user enters some numbers (like 129109212). Then this number filters where are only '0' and '1' left (1101). Then if the last number length is more then 4, then every section from 4 numbers converts to a decimal (from binary), called "res" now. if one of the "res" is more then 8, the whole entered number deleted from the queue and the next number converts. Then print all the results".

EXAMPLE (with 2 numbers):
Enter the number: 10203040506071
The binary is: 10000001
(here are two numbers: 1000 and 0001. they convert (8 and 1))
THE RESULT IS: 81

---

Enter the number: 11023232030232
The binary is:  11000
(Here are 1100 and 0 - 1100 is more than 8 (12) and number deletes from the queue)

---

THE END RESULT: 
1) 81

---END---
HERE IS THE CODE (LOGICALLY ALRIGHT BUT ERRORS OCCUR (reading error and so on(   ))

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <limits.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define QMAX 100
typedef long long int li;
struct queue {
    li qu[QMAX];
    int rear, frnt;
};

//FUNCTIONS FOR THER QUEUE
void init(struct queue* q) {
    q->frnt = 1;
    q->rear = 0;
    puts("--------THE QUEUE WAS CREATED SUCCESSFULLY!!!--------");
    return;
}

void insert(struct queue* q, li x) {
    if (q->rear < QMAX - 1) {
        q->rear++;
        //strcpy(q->qu[q->rear], str);
        q->qu[q->rear] = x;
    }
    else
        printf("---THE QUEUE IS FULL!---\n");
    return;
}

int isempty(struct queue* q) {
    if (q->rear == 0) return(1);
    else  return(0);
}

void print(struct queue* q) {
    puts("----THE ELEMENTS OF THRE QUEUE ARE: ----");
    int h;
    if (isempty(q) == 1) {
        printf("Очередь пуста!\n");
        return;
    }
    for (h = q->frnt; h <= q->rear; h++)
        printf("%lli\n", q->qu[h]);
    return;
}

li removeEl(struct queue* q) {
    int h; li x;
    if (isempty(q) == 1) {
        printf("Очередь пуста!\n");
        return(0);
    }
    x = q->qu[q->frnt];
    for (h = q->frnt; h < q->rear; h++) {
        q->qu[h] = q->qu[h + 1];
    }
    q->rear--;
    return(x);
}
int main()
{
    char str[20], inputStr[100];
    int i, num;
    printf("Enter the amount of numbers: \n"); scanf("%d", &num);
    struct queue* queue;
    queue = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    init(queue);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        li x;
        printf("Enter your string : "); getchar();
        scanf("%lli", &x); getchar();
        insert(queue, x);
    }
    puts("THE QUEUE IS: ");
    print(queue);

    int h;
    for (h = queue->frnt; h < queue->rear + 1; h++) {
        char inputStr[127], res[20];
        sprintf(inputStr, "%lli", queue->qu[h]);
        //DLETING EVERYTHING IS NOT 0 OR 1
        int j = 0;
        for (i = 0; inputStr[i]; i++)
            if (inputStr[i] >= '0' && inputStr[i] <= '1' || inputStr[i] == ' ' || inputStr[i] == '\0') {
                inputStr[j] = inputStr[i];
                j++;
            }
        inputStr[j] = '\0';
        printf("String after modification : ");
        printf("%s\n", inputStr); getchar();

        int len = strlen(inputStr);
        int temp[4];
        int k;
        char str[4] = "";
        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
            if (inputStr[i] != '\0' || inputStr[i] == '1' || inputStr[i] == '0')
                temp[0] = inputStr[i] - '0';
            if (inputStr[i + 1] != '\0' || inputStr[i + 1] == '1' || inputStr[i + 1] == '0')
                temp[1] = inputStr[i + 1] - '0';
            if (inputStr[i + 2] != '\0' || inputStr[i + 2] == '1' || inputStr[i + 2] == '0')
                temp[2] = inputStr[i + 2] - '0';
            if (inputStr[i + 3] != '\0' || inputStr[i + 3] == '1' || inputStr[i + 3] == '0')
                temp[3] = inputStr[i + 3] - '0';

            sprintf(str, "%d%d%d%d", temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3]);
            k = str - '0';
            //convertation into decimal system
            int counter = 1, timeless, decimal = 0;
            strcpy(res, "");
            while (k != 0) {
                timeless = k % 10 * counter;
                decimal += timeless;
                k /= 10;
                counter *= 2;
            }
            if (decimal > 8) { removeEl(queue->qu[h]);}
            else {
                char dec; dec = decimal + '0';
                strcat(res, dec);
            }
            strcat(res, '\0');
        }
        int num = res - '0';
        queue->qu[h] = num;
        printf("The decimal is: %d", queue->qu[h]);
    }


    /*
    fgets(inputStr, 100, stdin); getchar();
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; inputStr[i]; i++) {
        if (inputStr[i] >= '0' && inputStr[i] <= '1' || inputStr[i] == ' ' || inputStr[i] == '\0') {
            inputStr[j] = inputStr[i];
            j++;
        }

    }
    inputStr[j] = '\0';
    printf("String after modification : ");
    printf("%s\n", inputStr); getchar();
    int len = strlen(inputStr);
    enqueue(queue, inputStr);
    char num1[100] = "";
    int temp[4];
    int res = 0;
    strcpy(str, "");
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
        if (inputStr[i] != '\0' || inputStr[i] == '1' || inputStr[i] == '0')
            temp[0] = inputStr[i] - '0';
        if (inputStr[i + 1] != '\0' || inputStr[i + 1] == '1' || inputStr[i + 1] == '0')
            temp[1] = inputStr[i + 1] - '0';
        if (inputStr[i + 2] != '\0' || inputStr[i + 2] == '1' || inputStr[i + 2] == '0')
            temp[2] = inputStr[i + 2] - '0';
        if (inputStr[i + 3] != '\0' || inputStr[i + 3] == '1' || inputStr[i + 3] == '0')
            temp[3] = inputStr[i + 3] - '0';

        sprintf(str, "%d%d%d%d", temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3]);
        strcat(num1, str);
        strcat(num1, " ");
        sscanf(str, "%d", &res);
        printf("\nres is: %d", res);
        //RES is converted to number char
        //convertation into decimal system
        int counter = 1, timeless, decimal = 0;
        while (res != 0) {
            timeless = res % 10 * counter;
            decimal += timeless;
            res /= 10;
            counter *= 2;
        }
        printf("\ndecimal is: %d", decimal);
        if (decimal > 9) dequeue(queue);
    }

    for (int i = queue->front; i < queue->size; i++) {
        char str1[100] = "";
        int len = strlen(&queue->array[i]);
        int temp1[4];
        int c = 0;
        char decimals[32] = "";
        char deca[32];
        int res = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
            strcpy(deca, "");

            if (queue->array[i] != '\0' || queue->array[i] == '1' || queue->array[i] == '0')
                temp1[0] = queue->array[i] - '0';
            if (queue->array[i + 1] != '\0' || queue->array[i + 1] == '1' || queue->array[i + 1] == '0')
                temp1[1] = queue->array[i + 1] - '0';
            if (queue->array[i + 2] != '\0' || queue->array[i + 2] == '1' || queue->array[i + 2] == '0')
                temp1[2] = queue->array[i + 2] - '0';
            if (queue->array[i + 3] != '\0' || queue->array[i + 2] == '1' || queue->array[i + 2] == '0')
                temp1[3] = queue->array[i + 2] - '0';

            sprintf(str, "%d%d%d%d", temp1[0], temp1[1], temp1[2], temp1[3]);
            strcat(str1, str);
            strcat(str1, " ");
            sscanf(str, "%d", &res);
            printf("\nres is: %d", res);
            //RES is converted to number char
            //convertation into decimal system
            int counter = 1, timeless, decimal = 0;
            while (res != 0) {
                timeless = res % 10 * counter;
                decimal += timeless;
                res /= 10;
                counter *= 2;
            }
            char aka = decimal + '0';
            strcat(decimals, &aka);

        }
        //printf("%s --- %s", str1, decimals);
    }
    */
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int convertBinaryToDecimal(long long n)
{
    int decimalNumber = 0, i = 0, remainder;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        remainder = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        decimalNumber += remainder * pow(2, i);
        ++i;
    }
    return decimalNumber;
}
```

Comment: Please describe the error(s) with more detail.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code, either with a debugger or by printing out the intermediate variables?